# NodeJS - SHA256 Password Decryption

Tags: node.js, express, encryption

I'm currently learning about encryption/decryption password in NodeJS. In my code password format is sha256 & i get encrypt data. Now how can I decrypt that data?

```
exports.getHashedPassword = function(password){
    const sha256 = crypto.createHash('sha256')
    const hash = sha256.update(password).digest('base64')
    return hash;
}
__
var password = '11111111'
const password = helper.getHashedPassword(password);
console.log(password)// result:7nmXbJOA1eM3/BwJXs6MjyL5HzBs7rFh+lH+zt4sS6E=
```

Comment: https://www.techsolvency.com/passwords/dehashing-reversing-decrypting/

Answer (score 2):

SHA256 is a [hash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) function **not** an encrypting function.

Hashing is one way as it is "lossy" (many inputs are hashed to the same) -- in this case -- 256-bit|64-byte value.

For this reason, you cannot invert the function.